# Spring hibernate - unable to test insert

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to test my service layer with junit testing. Every thing works as expected except for insertion.

This is my configure test case for insertion:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:spring-servlet.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager",defaultRollback=true)
public class TestUserAccountDao {
@Autowired
UserAccountService userManager; 

UserAccount newUser;

@Before
public void init() {
    newUser = new UserAccount();
    newUser.setUsername("TestUser");
    newUser.setEmail("testEmail@gmail.com");
    newUser.setPassword("123456");
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    //userManager.remove(newUser);
    newUser = null;
}

/** test: void add(UserAccount)
 * */
@Test   //@Transactional
public void testAdd() {
    System.out.println(newUser);
    userManager.add(newUser);

    /*Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(newUser);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();*/
}
```

The problem I have that when I involved userManager.add(newUser), the UserAccount doesnt persist to the database. But if I switch to use commeting session, it works perfectly. I dont think there is any thing wrong with my spring-servlet.xml because I can test other methods successfully, and I didn't do anything complex about add(), simply session.save(UserAccount).

This is the stacktrace I got:

```
 INFO | 2014-09-05 10:12:43,268 | TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java | 298 | Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [DefaultTestContext@44d46936 testClass = TestUserAccountDao, testInstance = com.isad.test.dao.TestUserAccountDao@55477b87, testMethod = testValidateLoginByName@TestUserAccountDao, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@47ff07ce testClass = TestUserAccountDao, locations = '{classpath:spring-servlet.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
 INFO | 2014-09-05 10:12:43,271 | TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java | 276 | Began transaction (2) for test context [DefaultTestContext@44d46936 testClass = TestUserAccountDao, testInstance = com.isad.test.dao.TestUserAccountDao@2dda03f0, testMethod = testValidateLoginByEmail@TestUserAccountDao, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@47ff07ce testClass = TestUserAccountDao, locations = '{classpath:spring-servlet.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager@38598a4f]; rollback [true]
```

Answer (score 0):

The transaction is usually manage by the service layer (with Spring `@Transactional` annotation on service methods in your case). So when you test it you do not have to play with transaction (You do not have to open and close it).

And if you want to unit test your service layer you will have to mock your DAOs (persitance layer) with Mockito for example.